# jQuery hide and show text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a simple function in Jquery: when a button is clicked show the input text, when it's clicked again- hide the input text.

```
<div>
  <div id="btnNewGroup">New Group</div>
  <input type="text" id="newGroup" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

and this is the scrupt section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {
     if ($("#newGroup").hide()) {
           $("#newGroup").show();
     }

     else {
           $("#newGroup").hide()
     }
  });
});
```

when I click the button the text input is showing, when I click it again I want the input text to be hidden, but nothing happens.

Comment: use this js code

`$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {
     $("#newGroup").toggle()
  });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show / hide

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97gfU/)**

```
$("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {        
     $("#newGroup").toggle();        
});
```

The problem with the condition you have is that you are hiding the element instead of checking if it is hidden. You can `is`  with `:hidden` like is(':hidden') to check if element is hidden.

```
if ($("#newGroup").is(':hidden')) {
     $("#newGroup").show();
else  
     $("#newGroup").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

`if ($("#newGroup").hide())`

The hide function does not return a `boolean` value so you can't use it in an `if` statement. It returns a jQuery object which is *always* true so your second block never gets hit.

You can try two things:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {
     if ($("#newGroup").is(":visible")) {
           $("#newGroup").hide();
     }

     else {
           $("#newGroup").show()
     }
  });
});
```

Or a simple toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {
     $("#newGroup").toggle();
  });
});
```

Additionally, when working with selectors multiple times it's a good idea to cache the element - otherwise jQuery tries to find the element each time you try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {
     var $newGroup = $("#newGroup"); // Cache it here
     if ($newGroup.is(":visible")) {
           $newGroup.hide();
     }

     else {
           $newGroup.show()
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.toggle()` for hide and show alternatively in jquery

```
$("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {        
       $("#newGroup").toggle();        
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2GjQ7/1/)**

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) function

```
$("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {
  $("#newGroup").toggle()

});
```

---

Or use **[`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** pseudo selector with **[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2GjQ7/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {
      if ($("#newGroup").is(":visible")) {
           $("#newGroup").hide();
     }

     else {
           $("#newGroup").show()
     }
  });
});
```

**Note :**`hide()` function does not return boolean value. Use `is(:visible)` or `is(:hidden)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
 if ($("#newGroup").hide()) {
```

to (just one possible solution)

```
  if ($("#newGroup").css('display')=='none') {
```

Because $("#newGroup").hide() will always return true.
And here are the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {

     if ($("#newGroup").css('display')=='none') {
           $("#newGroup").show();
     }

     else {
           $("#newGroup").hide()
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the .toggle() function within the API.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById("username").style.display='block';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.