# Set model property from view

Tags: jquery, model

As a continue to the question here:
[jQuery hide and show text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300779/jquery-hide-and-show-text-input)

```
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="btnNewGroup" value="New Group" />
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GroupName, new { @id = "newGroup", @style = "display:none" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnNewGroup").click(function () {        
             $("#newGroup").toggle();        
        });
    });
    </script>
```

when I click on a submit button, I want my model property GroupName to get the correct value:
if the the text input is shown the property will get the value entered, if the text input is hidden so the propery value will be the string "Other Group".

Comment: id should be unique..!

Comment: you are right, I changed it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  if ($('#newGroup').is(':hidden')) {
    $('#newGroup').val('Other Group');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on Model.GroupName when the input text is hidden.